# Is there an editor with code block folding, one click dvi-ps-pdf compilation, etc?

Tags: editors, subversion, code-folding

I am a Windows user and using TeXnicCenter now. But I want to change to another one because TeXnicCenter does not provide us with a code block folding.

The new editor I want to use:

- runs on Windows.
- provides me with a code block folding.
- provides me with one click button to do "latex->dvips->ps2pdf".

Other optional things I need:

- Support Subversion.
- Free of charge.
- Support syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/). I think it supports all you need without subversions (but I’m not sure …).

For you one click compiling you can define your own “quickbuild” command.

**update:** The [feature list](http://texmakerx.sourceforge.net/#features) says, there’s SVN support

Comment: @xport: Hope you like it. Another nice feature is that you can create user macros and user commands even with Java Script, e. g. to easy access to often needed search and replace actions

Comment: I regret I did not know there is an editor like this. I am figuring out how to configure QuickBuild now.

Answer (score 4):

I refer you to [this list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/215).

I would also like to point out that emacs+auctex can do code folding. First turn on code folding mode: `C-c C-o C-f`. Then you can fold the current environment with `C-c C-o C-e`. You can also fold the current buffer, region, paragraph or macro by replacing the `e` in the previous command with `b,r,p,m` respectively.

I'm fairly confident AucTeX's `C-c C-c` is smart enough to handle your latex, dvips, ps2pdf combination. Although it does take a whole three keystrokes! (four if you have to save first). That said, I bet you'll find it quicker than using your mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read it and try one by one and I may change  my current decision.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has all that capabilities. You will find instructions on how to set up Notepad++ as an LaTeX IDE [in this StackExchange message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43984/9632).

[TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) is another free editor that has all your requested features (and a lot more), except the SVN-integration. May be you can convince the author to put in that feature in the next version.

Comment: +1 for Notepad++, it simply has amazing capabilities on a Windows box.

Comment: And there's a plugin for subversion - not tested, I'm using a local install of Git for version control on my thesis.